# how to bind data to gridview in windowsApplication C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have the below code in button. By clicking that button , i retrieve data from sql server and to display in GridView. I can retrieve and filled in dt.But my data are not shown in grid view,
What is theProblem? please crack me out.

```
       private void gvIPretrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        connstring();
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("gvretrieve_ip", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: is there any data in 'dt' after executing command?

Comment: Try adding dataGridView2.DataBind(); after dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is no Gridview in Windows Application.There is a control to show the data in the form of rows and columns i,e DataGridView.Here is the best useful [Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Fill-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx) for binding data from sql server database through datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try using dataGridView2.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

Answer (score 0):

Sir, asp.net or windows? You need to add `dataGridView2.DataBind();` after `dataGridView2.DataSource=dt;`

> Hope, it helps.